# How to initialize SelectCommand.Connection property in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized. I have done the coding in button click. Conn is my connection class's object. I have called this connection class in my button click class. Let me know why it shows error? I have already searched answer for this question in Stack overflow and I applied even though it shows the same error. The ddcode.selectedItem.Text is dropdown for select Employee name.

```
 string strQuery = "SELECT MachID, EmpCode, FROM LeaveApply where MachID='" + ddcode.SelectedItem.Text + "'",conn;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);
```

See it is my connection class

```
 public Connection()
    {

        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);
        cmd = null;
    }
```

And I have called this connection class in my button click function's class like

```
Connection conn = new Connection();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point actually creating a `SqlCommand` object because the `SqlDataAdapter` will do it for you.  In fact, it can even create the `SqlConnection` object for you.  If you need to reuse the connection then do this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, paramValue);
    // ...
}
```

and, if you don't need to reuse the connection then do this:

```
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, paramValue);
    // ...
}
```

If you really want to create a separate `SqlCommand` then do this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, paramValue);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the CreateCommand factory method of the connection object to create your command, then your command object will correctly use the connection object.

```
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
     conn.Open(); // Make sure connection is open.

     string strQuery = "SELECT MachID, EmpCode, FROM LeaveApply where MachID='" + selectedItem + "'";

     SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = strQuery;

     SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     sda.Fill(dt);
```

Alternatively you can manually tell the command to use the connection object

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

It sounds like jmcilhinney has a better answer for your purposes however.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the connection to your database. The connection will perform the following jobs.

1. Create a connection to database by using provided connection string.
2. Open up the connection bridge to transact the data.
3. Execute the provided query or Stored Procedure.
4. Fill the data in application's memory
5. Close the connection bridge to prevent the database.

Use the object of your own connection class.
Try it as follows:

```
using (Connection Con = new Connection()) {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    cmd.Connection = Con;

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    try {
        Con.Open();             
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        Con.Close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I have a separate connection class. I am just creating an object for this class in all my forms. In this button click class also I have created object for my connection class. So I think  again it not necessary write connection class in button click.

Comment: But you **shouldn't** be calling both `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and `sda.Fill(dt);` - that would in fact execute the statement **twice** .... do one or the other - but not both !

Comment: Please show your complete code as you are not opening the connection, by Con.Open(), before calling the Fill method. @marc_s Its my bad to not having notice on it even in my professional practice. Thanks to update my knowledge.